# Why should I initialize variables in a class?

Tags: php, class, variables, initialization

Why do I have to initialize variables in a class?

```
$test = new myclass();
class myclass {
    private $var; // WHY THIS LINE?

    public function sayHello() {
        $this->var = 'hello';
        echo $this->var;
    }
}
$test -> sayHello();
```

When I remove the line with `private $var;` this example works too.

Why do I have to initialize variables in classes?

Comment: if you initialize it dynamically it will be public by default, too.

Comment: Please, read manual carefully: http://php.net/oop. It is a feature, that may be used, or not: depends on situation.

Comment: Knowing that it's there at a glance is helpful. Having to troll through each method to discover the properties isn't productive.

Comment: PHP has no way of knowing the member's visibility (`protected` or `private`) if you do not tell it. The exception is `public` members, which do not have to be explicitly defined. This is true of most, if not all, object oriented languages that support member visibility.

Answer (score 10):

Initializing variables has some benefits:

- You declare that you intentionally want to use the variable name. This can help highlight typos which become undeclared varible name
- You can set the scope of the variable. Do you want it to be public, protected or private? You might want it to be static
- PHP has some info about what you're doing. It may help it to optimize for faster execution.

It's good practice to declare your variables, but it isn't a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but as I believe you mean why to use additional line of code while the whole code works as fine without it.
The answer is - of course you don't have to use `private $var;`. But despite the fact that it doesn't matter for the PHP engine it's really useful for you when your code grows. Imagine, that you've got a class that is a few thousand lines long. Only checking each time which of many variables you use only within the class (*private* ones) and which you can use outside (*public*) would be a disaster. If you can't see it now, don't worry, I'm sure you will discover its utility soon;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't declare an access specifiers like private then the default it's public.